# Android onBackPressed inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to control the back `Button` event inside fragment code.

**The situation is this:**

Inside my fragment i have a sliding panel. When the user tap the back Button, if the panel is expanded, I need to close it. If the panel is already close, I need to use my default `onBackPressed` (in the activity) that launch the `popBackStack()` method.

Any advice?

My activity onBackPressed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        // super.onBackPressed();
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add testing whether open or closed panel and accordingly perform the desired action.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a boolean value in SettingPrefences whether the panel is expaned or not and then by getting the preffrence value you can manage your backStack